# Laravel Cannot retrieve a specific record from a form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am outputting a list from a database table 'books' like this:

```
function edit()
{
    $books = Book::all();
    return view('layouts/editbooks', ['books' => $books]);
}
```

And displaying them like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')

@section('content')
<h1>Edit Book</h1>
<form action="{{url('editbook')}}" method="GET">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
     @foreach ($books as $book)
        <div>
            <label>{{$book->title}}</label>
            <input type='radio' value='{{$book->id}}' name='books[]'/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning form-control" value="Edit">
</form>

@endsection
```

I then want user to choose which record they want to edit by selecting a radio button, and upon clicking a submit button, redirect user to a new page with details of a book.

Therefore I am trying to get a book id from radio button and then if id matches, display everything from that record:

```
function editing(Request $request)
{
    $edit = $request->books;
    return view('layouts/editing', ['edit' => $edit]);
}
function updateEdit()
{
    $books = DB::table('books')->where('id', $edit)->first();
}
```

And that is displayed in a view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')

@section('content')
<h1>Delete Book</h1>
<form action="{{url('removebook')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
        <input name="name" type="textbox" value="{{ old('name', $edit['name']) }}"/>
        </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Delete Book">
</form>

@endsection
```

However I get an error message saying:

> Undefined index: name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laraveladvweb\resources\views\layouts\editing.blade.php)

What is causing the issue?

Comment: Dump the contents of `$edit['name']` in the view should probably be `$edit->name`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't $edit just the id of the book?

try this

```
function editing(Request $request)
{
    $edit = $request->books;
    $book = DB::table('books')->where('id', $edit)->first();
    return view('layouts/editing', ['edit' => $book]);
}

@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title')

@section('content')
<h1>Delete Book</h1>
<form action="{{url('removebook')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
        <input name="name" type="textbox" value="{{ old('name', $edit['name']) }}"/>
        </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Delete Book">
</form>

@endsection
```